# SOAP web service deserialization error in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, deserialization

UPDATE1: It's not that I don't want to show any code but not sure what to show in this case that would make a difference. And I can't possibly paste the xml response here as it contains sensitive information; but even if I can is that going to be of any use? It's not a bug that I can replicate with some dummy code; I can't even replicate the bug with real code!
Essentially I was given a SOAP web service and I added WSDL file as a service reference; just need to call one method on the service and all works fine for myself and another developer but doesn't work for a user.

Sorry for a long worded question.

I am consuming a SOAP web service (by adding the service as a service reference in VS2013). Everything works fine when I make a call to the web service directly in VS and then our application is deployed. I can still call the web service after deployment through our UI layer (it's also working fine for another developer) but when a user tries to make the same web service call with exactly the same parameters; the user got an error simply saying: `error happened during deserialization.`

I found this really odd as the only difference I can think of between user's call and my call to the web service is our usernames are different; but the error clearly shows it's not an authorisation or permission issue.

Since the web service is written by another team in the firm, I contacted the team and they told me their log shows no sign of error and their log also shows the web service produced the expected xml response for the user call (which is not surprising as the error happened during deserializing the xml response).

I am not sure how I can replicate this (everything works for me) not to mention fixing this. I am guessing the error is not within my code as the method I am calling to web service does return a strongly type object hence the service will do the deserialization for me. But how can this deserialization work for some people not others. Is there any configuration that requires special treatment?

Comment: Either enable [message logging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064(v=vs.110).aspx) and/or [network Tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the actual xml payload. Use those results to create an [mcve] and add that to your question. In its current form the best we and future visitors can do is guess.

Comment: Show us some code !!!

Comment: @rene Ok thanks. I agree I probably should tried more logging/tracing before asking here. The only reason is because it's deployed to production already so thought giving a try here just in case...

Comment: Are there enums used in the types you use to deserialize the xml to? If so check if those enum values are within the range you have designed for. That is at least something I have ben [bitten by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17834516/fail-early-or-clearly-throw-when-an-enum-cannot-be-serialized)

Comment: @rene thanks for the link. I will definitely double check.